# Check if Table tr has class then remove and add new class on Hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I'm trying to highlight table rows on mouse hover. The each row (tr) has a class either "even" or "odd" already. So, to highlight the row on mouse hover, I need to remove the CSS class "even" or"odd" from the row first. Please take a lot at my script:

```
$('tr').hover(function() {

  if ($('this').hasClass('even')) {
    $(this).removeClass('even');
    $(this).addClass('rowhover');
  }

  else {
    $(this).removeClass('odd');
    $(this).addClass('rowhover');
  }
},
function() {
  $(this).removeClass('rowhover');
});
```

But, it's not working. Can you point me the mistake? Thank you.

**Update 1:**

I used this toggleClass liket this

```
$("tr").hover(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("rowhover");
});
```

Then I used the firebug to inspect the element, the tr got class like this:

```
<tr class="even rowhover"> where it should be <tr class="rowhover">
```

Same result if I use sth like this:

```
$('tr').hover(function() {

    $(this).addClass('rowhover');
    },
 function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rowhover');        
});
```

My CSS for rowhover class

```
.rowhover {background:green !important;}
```

**Update 2:**

I tried the suggestion from Justin Johnson :

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('even odd').addClass('rowhover');
        },
    function() {
     $(this).removeClass('rowhover').addClass(this.rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
  });
```

I inspected the element with FireBug, here's the result:

```
//Notice the space in the class=" rowhover" when mouse hover
     <tr class=" rowhover">

 //Notice the space in the class=" even", class=" odd" when mouse out
 <tr class=" even"> or <tr class=" odd">
```

**Update 3 : It's working!**

I followed a post at [jQuery - Demonstrations and Examples of Tablesorter Plug-in](http://www.pewpewlaser.com/articles/jquery-tablesorter) but I needed to add !important to override the previous style like this :

```
tr.overRow td { background-color:#FFFF99 !important; border :2px; }
```

I added that rule to the bottom of style sheet of tablesorter, then used the following script to manipulate it:

```
// Adds "over" class to rows on mouseover
$(".tablesorter tr").mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("overRow"); });
// Removes "over" class from rows on mouseout
$(".tablesorter tr").mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("overRow"); });
```

Now, everything works as it is intended to. Thank you all for suggestion. Sorry for not mentioning at the first place that I'm using jQuery tablesorter plugin, and I just want to highlight the row on hover event.

:D

Comment: Regarding your update: see my solution. You probably want .even.rowhover, .odd.rowhover instead of just .rowhover ... or you could use !important, but that's a last resort.

Comment: @Kamal Yes, it's wrapped inside $(document).ready

Comment: I realised when you said you could see the classes in firebug :). Anyway I've tried your methods in FF locally here and it is working (seemingly with the toggleClass (highlights to green)). can you define 'not working'. Because in firebug if you can see the classes, it should apply?

Comment: The spaces are fine (as per update 2). Another silly question. Is your even and odd styling applying? Where is your css sitting? Are you sure that your page is picking it up?

Comment: When I hover on the row this styple applied

table.tablesorter tbody td {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

or this class applied 

table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
background-color:#F0F0F6;
}

instead of class rowhover which should override the previous class


Why class rowhover not override the previous even and odd?

Comment: In your update #2, you shouldn't have to worry about spaces in your class attribute. Does it work?

Comment: @ fudgey Yes, now it's working. Please check update 3. If you can, please mark of the reply as the Answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
if ($('this').hasClass('even')) {
```

to

```
if ($(this).hasClass('even')) {
```

remove the quotes around `this`.  Also, you need to reset the original class state *and* you can chain your functions:

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('even odd').addClass('rowhover');
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rowhover').addClass(this.rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
});
```

Comment: Man, can't believe I missed that. Good eye. (Somebody upvote this thing! I'm out!) :D

Comment: Syntax highlighting: it's not just for the pretty colors ;)

Comment: I tried but there's no rowhover class applied to the row, I got this from firebug : On the hovered-row <tr class=" rowhover"> On mouse-out <tr class=" even"> or <tr class=" odd"> 

Please notice the space in the class=" even", class=" odd", class=" rowhover"

Comment: The space shouldn't matter. If your style still isn't being applied, look to your CSS for the .odd and .even classes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try chaining your events.

```
$(this).removeClass('even').addClass('rowhover');
```

Secondly, why remove those classes? If you simply add the class and then override it in CSS by combining class names:

```
.even { background:black; }
.even.rowhover { background:blue; }
```

Comment: Check out Jusint's roundup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363104/check-if-table-tr-has-class-then-remove-and-add-new-class-on-hover-event/2363173#2363173 , though I don't think you need to remove and replace the even/odd class names.

Answer (score 0):

You could just leave the class "even" and "odd" and just add/remove the class "rowhover" on hover (so e.g. a highlighted TR would have the classes "even" and "rowhover"). Set the background-color (or whatever it is you use for highlighting the row) in "rowhover" to be "!important" in your CSS to override "even" and "odd".

That way you don't have to care what class the TR had before and simplyfy your code a lot, you'd just call "add rowhover" on hover and remove it on mouseout.

Comment: Why use `!important`? Wouldn't `.even.rowhover {/* css */}` or `.odd.rowhover {/* css */}` achieve a sufficiently greater specificity than simply `.even` or `.odd`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using regular,"pure" javascript? Seems to me as if you would use some javascript-library (e.g. mootools).

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code seems to be wrong:

```
if ($('this').hasClass('even')) {
```

**You are quoting `this` keyword, try this:**

```
if ($(this).hasClass('even')) {
```

Comment: Not sure and out of curiosity can the toggleClass be used here?

Comment: I think you're missing what he's trying to do.

Comment: @DN: fixed and looks like i have spotted the error in his code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

(As an alternative) instead of using jQuery for this functionality, just use the built in css functionality

instead of using a rowhover class in your css use

```
tr:hover
    {
        ...styles here
    }
```

Comment: It's a great idea if you can ignore IE6. Or, best, even, is to do both, and relegate the additional js only to IE6.